# Malicious PHP request/POST

Tags: php, post, request, bots, malware

A website of mine is getting attacked lately. I've cleaned every bit of code I can, but I really can't figure out how they are able to create files and even inject files. I've turned off all writing rights, even for me. I decided to log all requests from now on, until I get this stuff fixed.

Now I've already got one result, it's ment to mess something up for sure. But I just can't figure out what is happening..

The request can be found here:
https://pastebin.com/TQGnvQjz

Beginning of the file:

```
bsbcy=vasa&txhw=LCRrLzY6ZXVjbDoxLSZmIHdqNSI1LGA0NXYvLnFwf2NjIS4vfiR8YSk6fX8qdGkpNCY9N
```

I should note the way it's being printed to me, and what the URL looked like.
Firstly, the url was /index.php?bsbcy=vasa
So the first variable is a GET variable.

The second variable, is the POST variable.
Now this looks like some base64. I tried decoding it, but base64decode.org either spits out a .bin file full of gibberish, or if I turn on live converting, it spits out the same gibberish but without me having to download it.

Does anybody know what gibberish is supposed to be? I'm betting it's something that's supposed to inject or create a file. But I can't know until I'm able to decode it.

Thanks in advance!

Regards,
sanderbebo.

Comment: do you have the file that this request was send to? Before your cleanup? Probably the solution to your mystery is there - i.e. decoding procedure

Comment: Can you show us the code for a form. If you dont validate your fields correctly it's easy to take advantage of a form

Comment: well base64 is for encoding of binary into a textual representation. So if you decode it, you get binary. It might or might not be meaningful binary, but that's going to be what it is giving you back.

Comment: Anyway, any discussion of what is happening to your app is a bit futile, because you haven't given a concrete example of a breach (just some vagueness about creating files), haven't given a concrete example of how you've tried to secure it (again, vagueness about "writing rights" - right to what? The disk permissions? The database? Or some permissions to do actions within the application?). There's no info about the server or its config, and no details of the code which processes the URLs the attackers are making requests to. So how can we know what's wrong with something we can't see?

Comment: @SuperDJ The request is send to index.php. There is nothing there that handles POST requests.

Comment: @ADyson I've always seen base64 being used to encode complicated text (like CSS for a Wordpress theme) to something like an 'export/import' code. So I didn't really know that. Thanks for explaining :)

Also, I ment writing rights to disk. Also, I could give code. But it's practically an index.php file with only HTML in it (except for the part of starting a session). So I don't know how a POST request on there can do anything.

Comment: @PawełŁukasik You might be right. I'll go take a look in the backup I made of the infected file.

Comment: have you got any evidence that this request did actually do something malicious? Maybe it was an attempt that failed to achieve anything? You need to trace the request to some actual action that occurred as a result. Did you not have any request logging switched on before this? If you're using Apache it normally comes with logging switched on by default.

Comment: @ADyson No, this request did not do anything. But I thought it might still be useful. Should I wait for a request that does do something and place it here?

Comment: that might be of more use. Although it depends if your security steps have fixed the vulnerability or not. Since you went ahead and made a change without knowing the root cause of the issue, it's then going to be hard to know if you're still vulnerable or not. Anyway you didn't answer my question about logs. Most popular webservers have basic logging switched on by default, so I'm surprised if you don't have any historical logs. It would probably be easier to search in there for something with a timestamp that corresponds to when you know something bad happened, than to wait for a new problem.

Comment: @ADyson The only logs I have found prior to making a logging script myself, are logs that list which IP has requested a certain URL. It's called access.log, but sadly I can't see the content of POST requests in that log.

Comment: that's true, but if you can correlate the time of a request with the time of something going wrong, then it gives you a clue at least as to where to look in your code / setup for problems, even if you don't know exactly how it was done. If you can't figure it out just based on that, then you do at least then know what to look for in future, more detailed logs to see if the attacks are continuing. Also there's no guarantee that whatever caused the problem was done via a POST request. The vulnerability could just as easily be something else.

Comment: @ADyson I noticed that the files that were infected or newly created never showed any recent edit date. Always something from 2015/2016 or january to june 2017. So it's hard pinpoint where it's going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, never ever ever ever use anything any user sends you directly. anything you receive through GET or POST or whatever, sanitize it. The problem you are facing is not solved by blocking writing rights. blocking rights can always be altered with codes. Whoever is attacking you, is able to attack you because you are still live and allowing him an entrance.

Now am not sure what your code looks like but you might wanna really sanitize all data inputs before processing. also, you might wanna encrypt and decrypt all data with secret keys. That way if any data comes in and it is not in line with your encryption it returns null and does not process at all. It may seem a lot of work but you work more when an attack comes through.

Consider this article it could be useful. https://www.dreamhost.com/blog/php-security-user-validation-sanitization/

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I already put data sanitization in there after the first attack. This was one of my first PHP scripts so it wasn't in there yet.

But it seems to me they are not using the script's variables to infect the server. Since I'm still getting infections even though they are being checked and sanitized. Will see though how this goes on.

Comment: Well, there is also a chance they already have a door in your server. Since this seems an old script, am not sure if you remember all your scripts but you might wanna scan through all your files and be sure its all "as is". There may be a thing in your files allowing this. I would usually either create a new not-obvious-file or add my scripts to an existing file if I ever got to anyone's system.

Answer (score 0):

I'm now using cloudflare and since then, no more infections.

Also put in some more checks, i.e. refusing further connections if POST values are too long. Don't know if it works like I hope it does, but it doesn't hurt normal visitors, and should annoy bots. So that's good.

Thank you people for the advice, information and the help!